# 'this' and addEventListener in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, this, addeventlistener

When you click the text `But no success when you click me`, an error occurs. I know why the error occurs. My question is what is the best fix? The error occurs because when `x.a` is called when `mydiv` is clicked, `this` is `mydiv`. How can we make it so that `x.a` runs successfully when `mydiv` is clicked?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div id="mydiv">But no success when you click me</div>
    
     <script>
      var x = new Thing();
      var y = document.getElementById('mydiv');
      x.a();
      y.addEventListener('click', x.a, false);
      
      function Thing() {
       this.a=function() {
        this.b();
       }
    
       this.b=function() {
        alert('Success');
       }
      }
     </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The above HTML file is at http://globebop.com/intro/test/2.htm

Comment: `x.a` is not bound to anything. Replace `x.a` with `() => x.a()`.

Comment: Sorry, Toraz. That is wrong.

Comment: And it would be wrong because...??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`y.addEventListener('click', x.a.bind(x), false);`

When you bind an event listener to a method, at the time the method is called (when you click on a div/button) `this` is going to reflect the context from which the method has been called.

Comment: Thanks, gor181. That works well. That makes the value of 'this' be x rather than mydiv when you click mydiv and x.a is executed.

Comment: @JimAndrews Yes, he knows why it works. That's why he posted the answer.